# What are the coding-styles for grouping declarations of properties and corresponding synthesize calls?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, coding-style

I'm still learning, so I don't have my working convention yet for grouping my properties in header files, and the same is about synthesize calls. Sometimes I group them in one order, sometimes in another order. Also, I'm synthesizing those properties in one or two paragraph of calls, but I saw some people use different synthesize call for every property. However, my laziness tell me that approach is a little big coding overhead :)

Later, I'm adding new stuff as development goes thought, so very often, I end up in a sort of a mess IMHO :) I do understand and try to use as much MVCs as I can, but still some of my MVCs contain 20 - 30 properties because of a lot of graphics that are designed in IB. Later, I'm doing some refactoring but still curious maybe some of you have a strong rules for code cleanness?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With @synthesize I always put them on separate lines so each prop has its own synth directive, this really helps with version control and clarity.

Comment: Hm, you are right, it might be more clear and easy to track the changes when viewing differences. It looks like its the way I should go too :)